# Excel VBA: Hyperlink woes

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have the following lines of code within a loop:

```
Worksheets(mainsheet).Cells(BidItem, "K").Value = "Test " & BidItem

Worksheets(mainsheet).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets(mainsheet).Cells(BidItem, "L"), Address:="http://google.com", TextToAdd:="Test link"
```

At the time this executes,

```
Dim mainsheet As String
mainsheet = "Tester"
BidItem = 6                 ' (in this loop, it then counts to 7 and 8)
```

The result is I will get "Test 6" in K6, "Test 7" in K7, and "Test 8" in K8 -- but nothing in L6, L7, L8.

I've read every stackexchange and other forum I can find on Hyperlinks.Add and I cannot figure out why this does not work. It must be something with the Anchor:= but I'm not sure what. What's my error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `On Error Resume Next` when trying to debug your code.

```
Dim bidItem As Long, mainsheet As String

mainsheet = "sheet3"

With Worksheets(mainsheet)
    For bidItem = 6 To 9
        .Cells(bidItem, "K").Value = "Test " & bidItem
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(bidItem, "L"), Address:="http://google.com", TextToDisplay:="Test link"
    Next bidItem
End With
```

Note `TextToDisplay` not `TextToAdd`. That should have thrown an error.

Comment: AH. I was using On Error much earlier in the loop for something and forgot to remove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**TextToAdd** is not a parameter for **Hyperlinks.Add** method. Use **TextToDisplay** instead. [See the MS method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel).

```
Worksheets(mainsheet).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets(mainsheet).Cells(BidItem, "L"), Address:="http://google.com", TextToDisplay:="Test link"
```